# Gallery image(thumbnails) not changing on visual swatch Magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, swatches, color-swatches, configurable-swatches

Is there any way to change the Gallery(thumbnail) image on visual swatch, currently only the base image get changed, I need to replace all the gallery image with selected product images

[image]

Comment: Any error on the console? or magneto log file?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya no errors, actually you can see the first thumbnail ,that one only get changed on swatch(this is how magento default working). but i need to change the entire images with selected product, suppose i have a configurable product called jacket and i have choose the size xl and colour red so there is a simple product associated with this and it have some images this image should come here

Comment: for that you need to do the customization code there.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Thats what the help i'am looking for

Answer (score 0):

You need to add images to your associated product based on swatch color. Then it will change images.

Comment: Already there are image(more than 5)for each single products but when we choose configuration only base image get changed